# How to get values in app.wsgi_app into a variable in Flask

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda

I have a aws lambda function in which I have implemented Flask.
Used the prefixMiddleware to strip the '/catalog' from the URL.

```
class PrefixMiddleware(object):

  def __init__(self, app, prefix=''):
      self.app = app
      self.prefix = prefix

  def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

      if environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith(self.prefix):
          environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['PATH_INFO'][len(self.prefix):]
          environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = self.prefix
          return self.app(environ, start_response)
      else:
          start_response('404', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
          return ["This url does not belong to the app.".encode()]

app.wsgi_app = PrefixMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, prefix='/catalog')
```

This environ in class has a dictionary inside called 'searchlog'.
I want to fetch this dictionary.
Is there a way to fetch this dictionary in a variable.
Need Help.

Thanks

Comment: Require more detail, where is this `searchlog` field?

Comment: If I do print(environ) then I can see the searchlog field in the output.

Comment: ` I want to fetch this dictionary. Is there a way to fetch this dictionary in a variable` => you can just do `environ['searchlog'] ` in the `__call__` method

Comment: I want to get the searchlog outside the class. If you see app.wsgi_app is were the class returns. In the same way I want to return searchlog in a variable called work_log.

Comment: What do you want to do with that, that's why I said you should provide more example, what're you trying to do.

Comment: This searchlog will be used by a function.